# Populate vector of references to traits

Tags: rust, reference, traits

Rust noob here. How can I populate a vector of references to a trait with variables defined locally?

I tried something like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=526d9cb24aff67dfe28ebf749105d622)):

```rs
trait Trait {
    fn as_trait(&self) -> &dyn Trait;
}

struct Struct1 {
    value: i32,
}
impl Trait for Struct1 {
    fn as_trait(&self) -> &dyn Trait {
        self
    }
}

struct Collection {
    values: Vec<&'static dyn Trait>,
}

fn populate(coll: &mut Collection) {
    for i in 0..10 {
        let foo = Struct1 {value: i};
        coll.values.push(foo.as_trait());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut coll = Collection { values: vec![] };
    populate(&mut coll);
}
```

This obviously returns the following error:

```txt
error[E0597]: `foo` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:21:26
   |
21 |         coll.values.push(foo.as_trait());
   |                          ^^^-----------
   |                          |
   |                          borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                          cast requires that `foo` is borrowed for `'static`
22 |     }
23 | }
   | - `foo` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I also tried to use `lazy_static` macro without success ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7542e9decd25b4a294ac716951ea3a34)):

```rs
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

trait Trait {
    fn as_trait(&self) -> &dyn Trait;
}

struct Struct1 {
    value: i32,
}
impl Trait for Struct1 {
    fn as_trait(&self) -> &dyn Trait {
        self
    }
}

struct Collection {
    values: Vec<&'static dyn Trait>,
}

fn populate(coll: &mut Collection) {
     for i in 0..10 {
        lazy_static! {
            static ref foo: Struct1 = Struct1 {value: i};
        }
        coll.values.push(foo.as_trait());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut coll = Collection { values: vec![] };
    populate(&mut coll);
    
}
```

In this case the error is the following:

```txt
error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item
  --> src/main.rs:23:55
   |
23 |             static ref foo: Struct1 = Struct1 {value: i};
   |                                                       ^
   |
   = help: use the `|| { ... }` closure form instead
```

Comment: Why do you want your list to have references to `Struct1` values instead of the `Struct1` value itself? Your code as-is will not work because you push a reference to `Struct1` into the list but then the value will be dropped immediately before the next iteration of the loop runs, so you'd end up with a reference to an `Struct1` that no longer exists.

Comment: Try using `Vec<Box<dyn Trait>>` instead. `Box<dyn Trait>` is the intended way to store an anonymous trat. To store dynamically sized data like sized data, we need to either box it or take a reference to it. And since a reference would not live past the end of the function, boxing it is your only choice. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=91d9e5adcf3ee0e2c8ea5fbe4c4995a5)

Comment: Can you please elaborate what are you trying to do? You want to store into a collection Vector of objects that implement some trait. Is that right? If that's your objective, you can simply do as @Locke has said. It is not clear why you want to keep a reference to the struct (and not a boxed struct) any specific reason? A more common pattern is to box the structs (and compiler allows it - if your Type implements the trait) and the box can be derefed.